# How to make an iframe scroll while behind a full screen div

Tags: iframe, z-index

http://walker-arnott.com/standon/

Hi, I am trying to create an effect where I have transparent PNG images pushed to each corner of the screen, over the top of an iframe.  I have the visual effect that I'm after - however the iframe does not scroll.  I assume this has to do with the zindex I'm using.

Is there any way to get around this? either by changing the CSS or adding some javascript?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.top-left {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(TOP_LEFT/BACKGROUND_TOP_LEFT.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    z-index:10;
}
.top-right {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(TOP_RIGHT/BACKGROUND_TOP_RIGHT.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    z-index:10;
}
.bottom-left {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(BOTTOM_LEFT/BACKGROUND_BOTTOM_LEFT.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    z-index:5;
}
.bottom-right {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(BOTTOM_RIGHT/BACKGROUND_BOTTOM_RIGHT.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
    z-index:5;
}
.standon-iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index:-100;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="bottom-left">
  <div class="bottom-right">
    <div class="top-left">
      <div class="top-right">
        <div class="standon-iframe">
          <iframe src="http://standon-calling.com/about/" width="100%;" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JS, but I wonder if you could handle a scroll event and then pass it onto the iframe with Javascript.